# How to change video size on android Media Recorder

Tags: java, android, android-video-player, android-mediarecorder

I need to capture a video 480 * 480 in my android app, but it seems that the MediaRecorder can only support limited build-in sizes such as 1980*1080, 960*720, etc, almost all in 4:3 or 16:9.

Is there any method that I can capture that size of video or should I capture a 640* 480 video and then use some video lib to process it to 480 * 480?

Comment: The cameras are generally designed to support a specific aspect ratio or two, and they don't allow you (that I've seen) to select arbitrary dimensions like this, so that may be your best bet. Though in my personal opinion, if the data size is not a concern, I would recommend using the highest resolution that gets the best frame rate you want so you have a bit of leeway when modifying or working with your video, and then crop and down sample to 480x480 for the final result.

Comment: Is there any sample code about video cropping on android?

Comment: solved by using ffmpeg